# Sending a NSMutableURLRequest request with “Body Requests” In iOS

Tags: ios, json, google-calendar-api, nsurlrequest

I'm currently working with Google calendar API and allowing users to post event with attendees, however now I'm supposed to send a `POST` method that includes a "Request Body".

Here's the Request that I'm supposed to send :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<MyCalendorID>/events/<MyEventID>

Request Body :

{
 "end": {
  "date": "2015-05-19"
 },
 "start": {
  "date": "2015-05-20"
 },
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "nai.bhavesh782@gmail.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm positive that I'm doing something wrong in `[request setHTTPBody]` but that's the only thing that I could think about.

Please help

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669296/post-json-data-into-existing-object

Comment: same problem, have you find fix for it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585403/how-to-escape-body-characters-in-nsmutableurlrequest

Comment: @János i am post my answer check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            NSMutableDictionary *RequestDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            BOOL *remind_bool = false;
            NSMutableDictionary *remindDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];
            [remindDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:remind_bool] forKey:@"useDefault"];

            [RequestDict setObject:[eventInfoDict objectForKey:@"end"] forKey:@"end"];
            [RequestDict setObject:[eventInfoDict objectForKey:@"start"] forKey:@"start"];
            [RequestDict setObject:AttendeesArr forKey:@"attendees"];
            [RequestDict setObject:_txt_eventname.text forKey:@"summary"];
            [RequestDict setObject:_txt_desc.text forKey:@"description"];
            [RequestDict setObject:_txt_location.text forKey:@"location"];
            [RequestDict setObject:remindDict forKey:@"reminders"];
            [RequestDict setObject:@"tentative" forKey:@"status"];

            [RequestDict retain];

            NSLog(@"%@",RequestDict);

-(void)callAPIfortesting:(NSString *)apiURL withHttpMethod:(HTTP_Method)httpMethod
      postParameterNames:(NSArray *)params
     postParameterValues:(NSArray *)values postParameterDict:(NSDictionary *)RequestDict
{
    // Check if the httpMethod value is valid.
    // If not then notify for error.
    if (httpMethod != httpMethod_GET && httpMethod != httpMethod_POST && httpMethod != httpMethod_DELETE && httpMethod != httpMethod_PUT) {
        [self.gOAuthDelegate errorOccuredWithShortDescription:@"Invalid HTTP Method in API call" andErrorDetails:@""];
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a string containing the API URL along with the access token.
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?access_token=%@", apiURL,[_accessTokenInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"access_token"]];
        // Create a mutable request.


        NSUserDefaults *UserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [UserDefaults setObject:[_accessTokenInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"access_token"] forKey:@"AccessToken"];
        [UserDefaults synchronize];



        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

        // Depending on the httpMethod value set the respective property of the request object.
        switch (httpMethod)
        {
            case httpMethod_GET:
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                break;
            case httpMethod_POST:
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                break;
            case httpMethod_DELETE:
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
                break;
            case httpMethod_PUT:
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        // In case of POST httpMethod value, set the parameters and any other necessary properties.
        if (httpMethod == httpMethod_POST)
        {
            // A string with the POST parameters should be built.
            // Create an empty string.
            NSString *postParams = @"";
            // Iterrate through all parameters and append every POST parameter to the postParams string.
            for (int i=0; i<[params count]; i++) {
                postParams = [postParams stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",
                                                                  [params objectAtIndex:i], [values objectAtIndex:i]]];

                // If the current parameter is not the last one then add the "&" symbol to separate post parameters.
                if (i < [params count] - 1) {
                    postParams = [postParams stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
                }
            }


            NSLog(@"%@",postParams);

        }


        if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:RequestDict])
        {
            // Convert the JSON object to NSData
            NSData * httpBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:RequestDict options:0 error:nil];
            // set the http body
            [request setHTTPBody:httpBodyData];
        }

        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSLog(@"%@",request);

        // Make the request.
        [self makeRequest:request];
    }
}
```